# How can we forward declare enums?

Tags: c++

Do we have to declare an enum class before its enumerators are used?

If not, how do we forward declare enums?

The following program causes a compile error:

```
#include <iostream>
enum class Color;

int main()
{
    Color c = Color::Green;
}

enum class Color
{
  Red,
  Green,
};
```

Compiler:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Project1, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Project1.cpp
1>C:\Users\Admin\source\repos2\Project1\Project1.cpp(6,19): error C2027: use of undefined type 'Color'
1>C:\Users\Admin\source\repos2\Project1\Project1.cpp(2): message : see declaration of 'Color'
1>C:\Users\Admin\source\repos2\Project1\Project1.cpp(6,24): error C2065: 'Green': undeclared identifier
1>Done building project "Project1.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Forward declaration will tell the compiler that a class exists, but no details about it, so it won't allow using details about it before the actual declaration. As of that a forward declaration won't allow to use `Color::Green`.

Comment: You need *definition* of enum to use its value.

Comment: remove the comma after the Green enum value

Comment: @Henri, the trailing comma is valid.

Comment: @Henri the last comma is allowed in c++17 and removing the comma doesn't solve the problem

Comment: @t.niese then how do you make that program work (without changing the order)..

Comment: The only really useful thing that such a forward declaration of an enum class would do is to allow the use of *pointers* to objects of that class. (In much the same way as with opaque structure declarations.)

Comment: *Why* do you want the program to work without changing the order? Any particular reason?

Comment: @cigien well I was wondering that if this was a complex problem then it would be hard  arranging these in order

Comment: It shouldn't be really, just declare the enum before its first use, and you'll be fine.

Comment: Forward declarations are only useful when used for declaring pointers and references, where the *details* of the declared type are not needed. You can't forward declare a complex type like an `enum` or `struct`/`class` if your intent is to actually use the stuff that is inside of it. The compiler needs to see what that inside stuff is before it can then use them.

Comment: Why the "`1>`" prefix? Is it actually part of the output?

Answer (score -1):

You are doing this:

> *Opaque enum declaration:* defines the enumeration type but not its enumerators: after this declaration, the type is a complete type and its size is known.

Read about enumerations at *[Enumeration declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum)*.